# Update a field dynamically by specifying column name

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I dynamically update a field programmatically by specifying the column name in Flask-SQLAlchemy? I have a class `PTc`. It will only ever have one long row so I can pull all the info with the following:

```
Target = PTc.query.order_by(PTc.id).first()
```

I can manually update a field e.g. `Target.price = 2` then commit. How can I update dynamically? i.e. When the program runs, it may want to update the price, amount or availability depending on the condition.

If I save column name to a variable, `columnToUpdate = 'amount'` then try `Target.columnToUpdate = 10` it will of course fail because it thinks that is a column. Otherwise I am forced to check condition of each which could get cumbersome given the large number of columns :

```py
if columnToUpdate == 'price'
   Target.price = 20
elif columnToUpdate =='amount':
     Target.amount = 20

...

elif columnToUpdate =='XYZ':
     Target.amount = ABC
```

Documentation only specifies insert, delete and select with minimal detail. The class :

```py
class PTc(db.Model):
    # id column     
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    goldPrice       = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    goldStock       = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    goldPriceChange = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    goldHistory     = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    goldAverage     = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    rmPrice         = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    rmStock         = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    rmPriceChange   = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    rmHistory       = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    rmAverage       = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    gemsPrice         = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    gemsStock         = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    gemsPriceChange   = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    gemsHistory       = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    gemsAverage       = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    oilPrice         = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    oilStock         = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    oilPriceChange   = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    oilHistory       = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    oilAverage       = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

Comment: Have you tried `setattr(obj_name, "price", 20)` ?

Comment: Afraid no joy with that: `AttributeError: type object 'PTc' has no attribute 'setattr'`

Comment: What does the class PTc look like, is it a Json/dict?

Comment: Updated class in description, it's fairly similar to the examples given in their tutorial  https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/

Comment: @Murchie85 - [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) works for me. Note that it is a built-in function, not a class method.

Answer (score 1):

The `setattr(PTc, "goldPrice", 200)` is what I was looking for, thanks to Gord for the solution.

It would be interested to see if there was another SQLAlchemy specific method given the documented `class.field = x` convention prevents the use of a variable as the field and would seem remarkable if they hadn't accounted for that.

Comment: how did you commit this to the DB? Specifically, how did you use the setattr() call?

Answer (score 1):

That was extremely helpful! Thanks, @Gord Thompson and @Murchie85!

```
target = PTc.query.order_by(PTc.id).first()
setattr(target, column_name, data_to_insert)
db.session.commit()
```

This is the way to use it.
Basically, this way you can use dynamic value for the column_name.